# Is there a reason CiviMail won't send a draft if no recipients are selected?

Tags: civimail

Often, CiviMail users will want to send a draft email to someone for approval before they know the exact list of recipients.  However, you can't "Send Test" unless you meet all the requirements for sending the email itself - most notably, the list of recipients.

Is there a reason for this I can't think of?  I wanted to put it out here before I considered writing a patch for this.

Answer (score 3):

I would think this is just that the entire form is being validated. It would make sense that there is different validation for the preview than their is for sending.

-Steve